# ReferenceError when I add C# row to the JavaScript code in view razor page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this code in razror view page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">
            Click me</button>
        <p id="demo">
        </p>
        @{
            List<UserContact> userContacts = ViewBag.contacts;
            String contacts1 = Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Contacts.cshtml", userContacts).ToHtmlString();
        }
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var contacts2 = @contacts1;
            function myFunction() {
                alert(contacts2);
            } 
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

when I press button **Click me** I get this error:

**ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined**

Why I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea why I get this error?

Looks like you have some pretty broken HTML. You have assigned the `contacts1` server side variable to an HTML fragment:

```
String contacts1 = Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Contacts.cshtml", userContacts).ToHtmlString();
```

and then you injected it inside a  tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var contacts2 = @contacts1;
    function myFunction() {
        alert(contacts2);
    } 
</script>
```

which totally breaks your markup. Look at the source code of the generated page in the browser and you will see how broken it is.

> And how can I fix it?

It's not quite clear what you are trying to achieve so it's pretty hard to say how to fix this issue, but for starters you might try having valid markup and javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        alert('The button was clicked');
    } 
</script>
```

It looks like you are trying to load some markup from the server when the button is clicked. You might consider using AJAX if this is the case.

---

UPDATE:

It looks like you are trying to assign a server side string variable to a javascript variable. This can be done by properly encoding it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var contacts2 = @Json.Encode(contacts1);
    function myFunction() {
        alert(contacts2);
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Darin,That is exactly what i am doing.

Comment: What are you doing? You want to use AJAX? It's unclear to me what are you trying to achieve. Could you please explain how does the application should behave?

Comment: I need to pass contacts1 to contacts2 (i.e to pass string .NET type to the var Javascript variable)

Comment: Well in this case make sure that you are doing it properly, by JSON encoding it to avoid getting invalid markup: `var contacts2 = @Json.Encode(contacts1);`. I have updated my answer to illustrate it.